# How to add nested Registry Key/Value in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, registry

Given a registry path "\a\b\c\d", I would like to add a value to key 'd'. The catch is - I don't know whether a,b, or c even exist, and I want the code to generate them if they do not exist. Is there a quick way (using some .NET method I haven't seen) to do this?  I could go the route of iterating through registry keys and use the OpenSubKey/GetValue/SetValue methods to perform the process, but would like to avoid reinventing the wheel if I can...

N.B.: The behavior I am looking for is the same behavior you would get from running a .reg file (it will create the necessary subkeys).

Thanks,

Assaf

Comment: You could achieve that result by actually writing your keys to a .reg file, and run it with a system command from .NET, but it would be a quick-'n'-dirty solution, and I wouldn't really recommend it...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't know of a built-in, single call you can make to do this.  However, you don't need to call OpenSubKey/GetValue, etc.  A call to `CreateSubKey` will create a new key, or open the existing key if it exists.

```
RegistryKey regKey = startingRootKey;
string[] RegKeys = pathToAdd.split('\'');
foreach (string key in RegKeys) {
    regKey = regKey.CreateSubKey(key);
}
regKey.SetValue("ValueName", "Value");
```

Ignore the extra ' in there, I needed it to make the formatting look right.  ??

Also, be sure you test for exceptions when doing registry key adds... there's a lot security- and path-wise that could go wrong.  A list of exceptions to trap is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ad51f2dx%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

**EDIT**
I'm making this too complicated!  I just tested... the following will do exactly what you want:

```
RegistryKey regKey = startingRootKey;
regKey = regKey.CreateSubKey(@"a\b\c\d");
regKey.SetValue("ValueName", "Value");
regKey.Close();
```

It's smart enough to parse the nested path.  Just make sure you have the @ symbol, or it will treat the string is as if it were escaped.

Comment: RegistryKey implements IDisposable, so you're potentially leaking a bunch of objects.

Comment: Interesting what gets dusted off for comments.  13 years ago, I preferred to keep code in answers as simple as possible to focus on the question being answered.  These days, yeah, I would probably wrap the code in a using statement to show best practices, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything built in, but doing a string split on the registry path and then looping through it and doing [CreateSubKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms128495.aspx) (instead of `OpenSubKey` so it creates missing ones) on each part is ok in my view.